# Fading out/color overlay on background image

Tags: html, css, hover

I have replicated a demo of my problem but solution to a relatively simple problem:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/384reh1x/)

I have four circular divs each with a unique background image (That is why the bg image is inline) but I wish to fade out or overlay the image with a colour and ensure the text dosnt fade out but retains its full opacity.

I have tried numerous things such as simply just changing the opacity on the hover etc but struggling here.

```
<div class="faces-container">
<div class="faces" style="background-image: url('http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1697767/thumbs/o-GAME-OF-THRONES-facebook.jpg');">

  <span class="name">Dan</span>
</div>
</div>

.faces-container{
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
     -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 3s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 3s; 
}

.faces{
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition : all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition : all 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition : all 500ms ease-out;
  transition : all 500ms ease-out;
  color: transparent;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.faces:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px 5px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #aaa;
  box-shadow:       0px 0px 10px 5px #aaa;
  color: #F7CA18;
}
```

Comment: You want to make "Dan" text opacity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/384reh1x/2/)

I removed your inline `background-image` for the `.faces` and replaced it with

```
background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7) ), url('http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1697767/thumbs/o-GAME-OF-THRONES-facebook.jpg');
```

on your `.faces` class.

I didn't get the point about /unique/ name and inline style declaration. This makes no sense. You can just have it like that:

`<div class="faces face-1"></div>` and then `face-2` and etc, where all the common styles for the elements will be stored in `faces`, and the hover state will be handeled in `faces-x` and `faces-2`.

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
.faces:hover > span.name{
  opacity: 0.5    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```css
.faces-container,.faces,.name{transition : all 500ms ease-out;box-sizing: border-box}

.faces-container{
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: fadein 3s; 
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative
}

.faces{
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    transition : all 500ms ease-out;
    color: transparent;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0
}
.name{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0)
}
.faces-container:hover .faces{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #aaa;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0
}
.faces-container:hover .name{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #F7CA18;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1
}
```

```html
    <div class="faces-container">
   <div class="faces" style="background-image: url('http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1697767/thumbs/o-GAME-OF-THRONES-facebook.jpg');"></div>
    <span class="name">Dan</span>
    </div>
```